# Gnome Panel becomes fully transparent when window is not maximised!

Tags: themes, gnome-shell, panel, gnome-panel

In my Ubuntu 18.04 Top Panel becomes fully transparent when any window is not maximized.

When the window is Maximized
[image: When the window is Maximized]

When the window is not Maximized
[image: When the window is not Maximized]

**How can I resolve this issue?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the behavior in your question is from the user-shell theme.

you should look for the below values in a style sheet that you are using as a user-shell theme.

`#panel` -->> when no window is maximized.
`#panel.solid`  -->> when a window is maximized.

in below example I took `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css` file in my Ubuntu 18.04

at line number 658

```
/* TOP BAR */
#panel {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  /* transition from solid to transparent */
  transition-duration: 500ms;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 1.86em; }
```

and at line number 1950

```
/* panel color */
#panel.solid {
  background-gradient-direction: vertical;
  background-gradient-start: #58554d;
  background-gradient-end: #3f3e39;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
```

Changed to

```
/* TOP BAR */
#panel {
  background-color: green;
  /* transition from solid to transparent */
  transition-duration: 500ms;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 1.86em; }
```

and

```
/* panel color */
#panel.solid {
  background-gradient-direction: vertical;
  background-gradient-start: blue;
  background-gradient-end: blue;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
```

since i have changed the colors to green and blue in above. I should see top bar as Green color when no window is maximized. and Blue color when a window is maximized.

here are some screenshots.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Woah Ubuntu 18 Gnome sure is beautiful ! I never tried it before

Comment: Adding #panel.solid to the theme css didn't work to me. Do you know if this behavior does not apply to 20.04+ or if this is specifc ubuntu theme thing?

Comment: @euDennis which theme did you change?

Comment: I've tried with Materia Dark Theme (https://github.com/nana-4/materia-theme).

But the behavior of solid vs transparency panel was removed from the main theme, wasnt?